# Noise Reduction for Video in Blender

Tags: video

I have footage of noisy HD video (too dark) and wonder if Blender's noise reduction applies to video. There is also this [Blender add on](https://www.blendermarket.com/products/render-cleaner-noise-reduction) that is available for a nominal fee, but again, there is no indication that it works for video and the seller cannot be contacted. Can anyone advise on noise reduction for video in Blender? I have tried noise reduction in DaVinci Resolve and it works a treat, but hope the same can be done in Blender...or better. Just to be clear, because some are saying 'duplicate' this is for VIDEO not 3D. V I D E O.

Comment: In my opinion, to process video, stick to a video editing app. If resolve does a good enough job for you, then use it. blender is terrific for creating and animating in 3d, but it is light years away from the maturity of  dedicated video apps when it comes to video editing, compsiting or post-processing. If you are willing to spend some money into cleaning noise use [NeatVideo](https://www.neatvideo.com/) (not compatible with blender)

Comment: Blender is a bit of a struggle as an NLE, but I was surprised it can do what it does. There are times when it can be useful for intro/outro graphics. Perhaps for 'add-on' developers reading this, they may want to make something for video reduction noise. One of this issues I have with DaVinci Resolve is that when you use Lite (their free version) it disables one of your GPU's (my workstation has two) and I do not have cash for the paid version, yet. I don't think Blender would ever disable my GPU's. Today, maybe Blender sucks as an NLE, but maybe it won't tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Cycles noise reduction introduced in recently released Blender 2.79 version works exclusively for rendered images because it specifically uses information from the 3D scene to make an educated approximation, as far as I know.

As such it would not work for random video files since no 3D information would be available in most situations

Everything else that uses the Compositor and/or Video Sequence Editor should be able to work as well for externally obtained footage, as long as it does not rely on data obtained from 3D rendering, like render passes, layers, or any other buffered data from a virtual model.

The mentioned addon seems to be used in the node editor as a node group based approach, so in theory it should work with any externally obtained footage.

Just use an <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Input > Image* or *Input > Movie clip* to insert your video sequence and use the desired nodes as recommended.

**Disclaimer**: Whether the algorithms or processes used in those nodes will work correctly or satisfyingly in your particular footage or specific type of noise is unknown.

Those nodes were made specifically with Raytracer bound noise/fireflies in mind, that have particularly very high peaks, so it may not work well of the low intensity noise or your particular case.